# Mongodb dosn't find the document with one specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[Document is exist but when it filtered it doens't match!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUU8u.png)

Hello, I found a new bug in my project. I'm using nodejs backend and mongodb database.
I'm succcesfully inserting a document. But one specific field("proje_ortagi") is confusing my mind. Because when I filtered documents as "_id" field. All documents is responsing. But When I filtered documents as "proje_ortagi" some documents don't come as response. Why does this happen?
I check tye type of "proje_ortagi"value. It is string. Thats good for me, but ı can't resolve this bug. Can anyone help ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide your schema and query please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

data

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    "proje_ortagi": "ipekyolu",
    "give_id": "M_685421"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    "proje_ortagi": "1",
    "give_id": "1"
  }
]
```

find

```
db.collection.find({
  "proje_ortagi": "ipekyolu",
  "give_id": "M_685421"
})
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "give_id": "M_685421",
    "proje_ortagi": "ipekyolu"
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8-J0tFCyvYh)